# What Shimano jockey wheels are compatible with my old Shimano 105 9-Speed Derailleur?

Tags: road-bike, shimano, derailleur-rear

I'm in the process of getting my Cannondale CAAD serviced, which I reckon is from about 2006 (I got it second hand). I have had the rear cassette and chain replaced, like for like, but the bike shop say the Shimano 105 9-Speed rear derailleur jockey wheels are very worn and may contribute to gear slippage and poor gear changing.

I can't seem to find jockey wheels specifically for the old 9-Speed 105 derailleur. Will the "Shimano RD 5700 Jockey Wheels" for the newer Shimano 105 10-Speed derailleurs be okay for use?

Comment: Are they 10 or 11 teeth jockey wheels?

Comment: I'm 90% sure they are 11 teeth, but will need to confirm (in a few days). Would that be good news if so?

Comment: Well it would leave you with more options :)

Comment: Ok, I have checked, it's 11 teeth.

Comment: Shimano is good about putting model numbers on their stuff. What exact model number is your rear derailleur? It'll probably be a RD-5xxx.

Answer (score 1):

Here you go, VeloOrange has a part for that: http://store.velo-orange.com/index.php/components/shifting-freewheels-cassettes/parts-maintenance/vo-grand-cru-sealed-bearing-universal-jockey-wheels.html

Answer (score 0):

Assuming my comment above, if your rear derailleur is either RD-5500 or RD-5501 you can find the parts list [here](http://techdocs.shimano.com/media/techdocs/content/cycle/EV/bikecomponents/RD/EV-RD-5500-1736_v1_m56577569830609118.pdf) and [here](http://techdocs.shimano.com/media/techdocs/content/cycle/EV/bikecomponents/RD/EV-RD-5501-2173A_v1_m56577569830609119.pdf), respectively. Which means you'll either need shimano parts:

RD-5500: *5UN 9806* and *5UN 9807*

RD-5501: *Y-5UN 98060* and *Y-5UN 98070*

A quick Googling shows you should be able to pick up a set for ~ $15.

As a side note, from experience, "close" is not good enough when it comes to pulleys. There are small differences in the size, shape, and especially width of the pulleys from model to model. So get exactly what you need. It might seem like a 10 speed pulley will fit, but you'll get it all put back together and then notice a squeaking noise from improper fit.